# NO INPUT FILE SPECIFIED - Codeigniter on IIS

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

I am stuck with Codeigniter v2.2 on IIS. I have PHP installed and configured and when I write plain PHP code, it works including the hyperlinks, but when I try to access any method of the CI controller, I get the error message "No input file specified". Below is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My config.php settings are as follows:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you have to read this guide:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installation-Tips

It helped many of us to understand why that errors is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the link given by PumpKing and found that I made a silly mistake. Here's what I did and got it working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="MyRule">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I changed the following code:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

To

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Changed Settings in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

It worked for me but url is now like http://www.example.com/Admin/index.php?/Login

It is containing index.php? , anyway site is working now. I'll figure out the url problem also.